# "Quidam usque adeo Demeae sunt, ingenioque agresti, ut vix salutati resalutent."

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation

In the *colloquia familiara* of Erasmus [we find](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/erasmus/coll.shtml):

> Quidam usque adeo Demeae sunt, ingenioque agresti, ut vix salutati resalutent.

What I have:

> Some are so Demea with uncultivated natural character to the extent they hardly greet back when greeted.

I obviously got the first part wrong, how to parse it and who is *Demea*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be a reference to the character Demea in Terence's *[The Brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelphoe)* -- a harsh, ill-tempered, strictly authoritarian father (at least at the beginning of the play). "Some people are such Demeas, and so rude of character, that..."